# WCF 2 cpu communication

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Need help!
Im trying to make one cpu use WCF Service that is selfhosted on another cpu in one subnet.
address = "http://192.168.0.107:55533/WCFTest"
binding = "basicHttpBinding"
On the client i specify the same adress and it works fine, but...
Each time the computer connects to the router it gets a different ip adress (not always but it could be), and the client machine would be having problems connecting to service if the address changes.
Is there some way how can client machine connect to server machine using mac address fo example, or something else but no making any additional setting to router because later it could be different subnets?

Thank you!

Comment: Curious question: How do you tie up instance of WCF service to specific CPU?

Comment: Maybe WCF Service registry and WCF Discovery can be help here. It maybe overkill in this scenario though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some DNS resolution name instead of using IP address.

You could also use Azure WCF relay services = have an endpoint relay on the cloud that doesn't change.

Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it

Getting started :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/service-bus-relay-tutorial